# React: How to pass data from 2 different API as props to a single component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page, (index.js) which contains component (slider.js). On index.js I am consuming 2 separate API. Everything works if I send the data from the 1st API to 1 component, and the data from the 2nd API to a different component.

However, I want a single component to receive some of the values from the 1st API along with some of the values from the 2nd API.

```
export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const apiUrl = 'https://api-1.com'
    const res = await fetch(apiUrl)
    const data = await res.json()

    const apiUrl2 = 'http://api2.com'
    const params2 = 'featured'
    const res2 = await fetch(apiUrl2)
    const data2 = await res2.json()

    return { data, data2 }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //logPageView()
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div id='slider'>

          {this.props.data.map(function (post, i) {
 return (
              <Slider
                api1postSlug={post.slug}
                //api2category={post2.slug}
              />
            )
})}
</div>

}
```

How would I pass the props from data2 along with `{this.props.data.map(function (post, i) {`

Comment: What is the data structure of the json result of API 2?

Comment: API 2 has a completely different structure but only 3 fields in total (no loop), which are used to complement the data from API 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **API 2** has the same data structure and rows of **API 1**, you can do it like so:

```
export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const apiUrl = 'https://api-1.com'
    const res = await fetch(apiUrl)
    const data = await res.json()

    const apiUrl2 = 'http://api2.com'
    const params2 = 'featured'
    const res2 = await fetch(apiUrl2)
    const data2 = await res2.json()

    return { data, data2 }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //logPageView()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='slider'>
        {this.props.data.map(function (post, i) {
          return (
            <Slider
              api1postSlug={post.slug}
              api2category={this.props.data2[i].category}
            />
          )
        }, this)}
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The data structures of the 2 API are completely different.

Comment: Your code gives error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an if condition before returning as following.

```
render() {
    if(this.props.data && this.props.data2) {
        return (
            <div id='slider'>
                {this.props.data.map((post, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Slider
                            api1postSlug={post.slug}
                            api2category={this.props.data2[i].category}
                         />
                    )
                }, this)}
             </div>
          )
     } else {
         return (
             <div id='slider'>Loading...</div>
         )
     }
 }
```